# spring mvc cannot mapping request to other view name

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a controller in spring mvc:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/advertiser")
public class AdvertiserController {


@RequestMapping(value="/add2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView add2(ModelAndView mav){


        mav.addObject("command", new Advertiser());
        mav.setViewName("advertiser/add");

        return mav;
}
}
```

My viewResolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
  p:prefix="/WEB-INF/"
  p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

You may see, i have mapped the request to `/advertiser/add2` url and i want to serve it with the view named add.jsp (`advertiser/add`). However when run the web app, it always show up the add2.jsp (`advertiser/add2`) page. My jsp views are in `/WEB-INF/advertiser` directory.

What i did wrong here?

Comment: Try clean your project and rebuild it

Comment: not help at all :( I even restart my machine.

Comment: How about clear your browser cache?? Or maybe you should try in private mode. 

I think your code seems right

Answer (score 0):

I think your url mapping is incorrect.
try this.Remove advertiser from setViewName.

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/advertiser")
public class AdvertiserController {
@RequestMapping(value="/add2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView add2(ModelAndView mav){


        mav.addObject("command", new Advertiser());
        mav.setViewName("add");

        return mav;
}
}
```

Comment: It's still showing the add2.jsp view after change as you suggested. In my WEB-INF directory, there are lot of directories not only advertiser. My prefix in viewResolver, i just define "/WEB-INF" so i think "advertiser/add" is needed, change it to "add" i think spring will point to WEB-INF/add.jsp.